# How do I change the size of the legend text in the risk table using R package survminer?

Tags: r, survminer

I need help. I did lots of online research trying to find a solution to change the size of the legend text in the risk table using R package survminer. Everything else in the KM plot is adjustable but I cannot change font size for the "Male" "Female" in the lower left corner next to the risk table. Is there any way to change the size? the default size is too large. I also don't want to use color to replace "Male" and "Female". Thanks a lot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUP8T.png)

tried many solutions and nothing worked.

Comment: maybe use F2 to inspect the source of the plot function and edit it yourself. ie create your own custom version

Comment: Thanks. So it can't be easily adjusted?

Comment: Yes it can be easily adjusted, you can manually change the values in the ggplot2 object; I'll write up an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can change values within the ggplot object, e.g.

```r
library(survminer)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> Loading required package: ggpubr
library(survival)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'survival'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:survminer':
#> 
#>     myeloma

fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)

plot <- ggsurvplot(
  fit,
  data = lung,
  size = 1,                 # change line size
  palette =
    c("#E7B800", "#2E9FDF"),# custom color palettes
  conf.int = TRUE,          # Add confidence interval
  pval = TRUE,              # Add p-value
  risk.table = TRUE,        # Add risk table
  risk.table.col = "strata",# Risk table color by groups
  legend.labs =
    c("Male", "Female"),    # Change legend labels
  risk.table.height = 0.25, # Useful to change when you have multiple groups
  ggtheme = theme_bw()      # Change ggplot2 theme
)

plot$table$theme$axis.text.y$size <- rel(0.5)
plot$table$theme$axis.text.y$colour <- "black"

plot
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Does that answer your question?